# javascript string.replace $1 if it is a certain value?

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, replace

Is there some way to check the value of `$1` and if it is equal to `"left"` then replace with `"newleft"`?

Something like this: `str.replace(re, 'Blah blah $2, $1="left" ? "newleft": "something" ');`

Comment: Can u give sample input and output?

Comment: Use a callback function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: thanks CBroe, I managed to solve it by looking at some callback examples like you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a callback function as the second argument of [the string place method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), the captured strings from your regular expression will be passed as arguments to the callback function. You can use these arguments to return a new string, and perform any necessary logic on the captured strings.

### Example 1:

```
'left, right'.replace(/(.*),\s(.*)/, function(match, p1, p2) {
    return 'Blah blah ' + p2 + ', ' + (p1 === 'left' ? 'newleft' : 'something');
});
```

#### Response:

```
"Blah blah right, newleft"
```

### Example 2:

```
'top, right'.replace(/(.*),\s(.*)/, function(match, p1, p2) {
    return 'Blah blah ' + p2 + ', ' + (p1 === 'left' ? 'newleft' : 'something');
});
```

#### Response:

```
"Blah blah right, something"
```